# Possible to extend NodeJS resolver?

Tags: node.js, ts-node

I would like to automatically inject a condition to the NodeJS resolver.

My projects use the [exports field](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_conditional_exports) with exports depending on the configuration I am running `(test, development, prodtest, default etc)`

This is easily configurable in webpack/jest, but with node I have to add the `--conditions` argument to each app.

I have a script that automatically runs to inject generalized mocks for external libraries in development:

```
node -r ../mocks/inject ...
```

```
var Module = require('module').Module;
Module._nodeModulePaths = (from) => { ... // inject mocks }
```

However, for my own libraries I would prefer to use the conditional exports.  Can I add the conditions to NodeJS in this script (to keep all the redirection in one place), rather than use the command-line argument?

I'm using ts-node if that makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

In the end, is simply achieved by using `enhanced-resolve` to `_resolveFilename`

```js
function enhancedModuleResolve(...modules) {
  const Module = require('module').Module;

  // NOTE: __dirname is where I keep some external mocks
  const resolver = require('enhanced-resolve').create.sync({
      conditionNames: [process.env.CONFIG_NAME, 'require', 'node', 'default'],
      extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.node', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      modules: [__dirname, 'node_modules'],
    })

  // NOTE: If we redirect all resolutions, breakpoints stop working
  // Just redirect my own packages (and whichever external API's
  // I want to have mocked) and everything works correctly
  const toResolve = ['@mypackages', ...modules]
  const oldResolve = Module._resolveFilename
  Module._resolveFilename = (request, parent, isMain) => {
    return toResolve.find(m => request.startsWith(m))//paths
      ? resolver(parent.path, request)
      : oldResolve(request, parent, isMain)
  }
}
```